# Unable to display multiple readonly fields in Django admin, only one will display

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to display two new rows (fields) in the "posts" section of django admin which are read-only fields that take data from two other database columns. My code works, but it will not create two new fields, it only displays one.

I'm relatively new to Django and python, and I'm struggling to figure out how to do this. I spent too much time trying different things only to have no success.

In the context of my test, I want to see two readonly fields called "New row 1" and "New row 2", which take the data from two database columns called "est_completion_time" and "downtime". I can only see "New row 2" on the output.

[image]

This is my code in admin.py:

```
@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = JBForm

    exclude = ['est_completion_time'] # hide this database column
    exclude = ['downtime'] # hide this database column

    readonly_fields = ['placeholder_1'] # display this one
    readonly_fields = ['placeholder_2'] # display this one

    @admin.display(description="New row 1")
    def placeholder_1(self, obj):
       
        return obj.est_completion_time # a new readonly field which should display contents of 'est_completion_time' column

    @admin.display(description='New row 2')
    def placeholder_2(self, obj):

        return obj.downtime # a new readonly field which should display contents of 'downtime' column
```

After reading through the docs I couldn't find a solution:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try this `readonly_fields = ['placeholder_1', 'placeholder_2', 'placeholder_3']`

Comment: thanks, yes it works also with the parentheses for example - ('placeholder_1', 'placeholder_2')...As I'm new to python, I'm getting quite confused when I see square brackets and such. It will come naturally to me eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to specify the `excluded` and `readonly_fields` once.

```
@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = JBForm

    exclude = ["est_completion_time", "downtime"]

    readonly_fields = ["placeholder_1", "placeholder_2"] # display these two

    @admin.display(description="New row 1")
    def placeholder_1(self, obj):
        return obj.est_completion_time 

    @admin.display(description="New row 2")
    def placeholder_2(self, obj):
        return obj.downtime
```

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem. And you know I actually figured it out about 40 minutes ago myself. I knew it was going to be something as silly as that. But I'll give you the points anyway